# prepend the first line of a file to every line of the rest of the same file

Tags: text-processing

I'd like to get the first line out of a file and put it at the beginning of every line of the rest.
For example, how do I transform this:

```
black
widow
card
Friday
berry
```

into this?:

```
black: widow
black: card
black: Friday
black: berry
```

Is it possible to do this without explicitly creating extra files and variables?

Answer (score 3):

With simple `awk` command you can do it:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {a=$0;next} { printf("%s: %s\n",a,$0)}' file_name
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Is it a bad idea to do the same thing with sed?

Comment: @stacko see other answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the *best* way to do it in sed, but:

```
$ sed '1{h;d;}; G; s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2: \1/' file
black: widow
black: card
black: Friday
black: berry
```

Explanation:

- `1{h;d;}` for the first line, copy pattern space to hold space and then delete
- `G` append a newline to the contents of the pattern space, and then append the contents of the hold space to that of the pattern space. We now have the right two words in pattern space, but in the wrong order and with the wrong separator (`\n` instead of `:`)
- `s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2: \1/'` swap the parts before and after the newline, replacing newline with a colon and space

Comment: Explanation...?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv added ...